# ask in a conditional if a key exists and if it's true in python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

i want to filter in a conditional if a key exists, and if it's true. Is there a way to make this shorter and more efficient?

```
d = {'x': True}

if 'x' in d and d['x']:
   print('good')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not much shorter but definitely more idiomatic and efficient (since it only does a single lookup regardless if the key exists) with [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). If the key does not exist it will return `False`:

```
if d.get('x', False):
    print('good')
```

`.get` will return `None` by default if `False` would not have been provided, so in most contexts this is equivalent to

```
if d.get('x'):
    print('good')
```

Comment: `if d.get('x') is True:` perhaps, since many other values are truthy

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yeah, depending on context that might be better